# In how many ways can you select $4$ different numbers from the numbers $1,2,..,15$

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can you select $4$ different numbers from the numbers $1,2,..,15$ so that no pair of numbers among the selected ones are subsequent numbers.

I turned this into a minor problem. I assumed that we have $5$ numbers and we want to choose two different numbers so that no pair of numbers among the selected ones is subsequent. I came to the conclusion that it will be $5$ choose $2$ and then minus all subsequent pairs that I calculated in my head. But I wonder if there is a better method that can be applied to $15$ numbers.

Also, how would you make this problem more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember writing a generalization to this a long time ago. I'll paste it here. Overall it's pretty intuitive to come up.

**Generalization**

The number of ways to create a subset of $k$ elements denoted by $e_1<e_2<..<e_k$ from $\{ 1,2,...,n \}$ such that the members of the subsets differs at least $y$ is $\binom{k+n-y(k-1)-1}{k}$

**Proof:**

To construct a unique subset we need:

1. A variable ($a$) that states the distance between $1$ and the first element of the subset.
2. $k-1$ variables ($d_1,d_2,...,d_{k-1})$ that states the distance between $e_1$ and $e_2$, $e_2$ and $e_3$, and so on.
3. A variable ($b$) that states the distance between $e_k$ and $n$.

And the sum of all the variables above will always be equal to $n-1$. So, we have:
$$a+d_1+d_2+...+d_{k-1}+b=n-1 $$
To apply stars and bars for non-negative integers we need to remove the restriction of $d_i \ge y$, we do this by adding $y$ to each of $d_i$:
$$a+d_1+d_2+...+d_{k-1} + y(k-1)+b=n-1$$
$$a+d_1+d_2+...+d_{k-1}+b=n-1-y(k-1)$$
By stars and bars, the amount of non-negative integer solutions the equation is $$\binom{k+n-y(k-1)-1}{k}$$

---

For the question here, $n=15,k=4,y=2$. So the answer is
$$\binom{4+15-2(4-1)-1}{4}=\binom{12}{4}$$

Comment: For usefulness of a generalized solution, (+1)

Comment: I don't quite understand the purpose of the variable a, if we go back to the original problem what does each of these variables (not in the formula but in the proof) represent?

Comment: for example how do we know that the sum of these variables is always n-1?And what do you mean by starts and bars?

Comment: @Negative Creep Try with a specific example, what is the $a,e_1,...,b$. Try to look up Stars and Bars

Comment: @NegativeCreep Say $n=6,k=3,y=2$ so $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Note that $\{2,4,6\}$ satisfies. $a$ is the distance between $1$ and the first element of the subset (which is $2$ in this case), so $a=2-1=1$. $e_1$ is the distance between $2$ and $4$: $e_1=4-2=2$. $e_3=6-4=2$. $b$ is the distance between last element and $6$ so $b=6-6=0$. We always have $a+e_1+e_2+e_3+b=5=n-1$ (If you can't see this, try expressing the sum in the number line).

Comment: thanks, now I understand this part but how do we remove non-negative integers? I mean why do we add y? Why is it y(k-1) and in one equation you add this and in the other one you subtract this?

Comment: @NegativeCreep We want to know the number of solutions of $a+e_1+..+b=n-1$ where $a,b\ge 0$ and $e_i\ge y$. We can't do stars and bars as we need to change the condition $e_i\ge y$ to $e_i \ge 0$. We do this by substituting $e_i=f_i+y$ where $f_i\ge 0$. Now it becomes $a+(f_1+y)+..+(f_{k-1}+y)+b=n-1$ or $a+f_1+f_2+...+b = n-1 - y(k-1)$. Now we can apply stars and bars as $a,f_i,b \ge 0$.

Comment: @NegativeCreep Stars and bars says that the number of non-negative integer solutions to $a_1+a_2+...+a_n=k$ is $\binom{k+n-1}{n-1}$. There are nice proofs online.

Comment: Oh I'm familiar with that didn't know the name but it looks like you mixed your formula with the stars and bars formula, but how did you get the formula you got in the end? How did you go from 2 equations to the formula? How did you get +−(−1)−1 choose ?

Comment: @NegativeCreep Assuming you've understand until $a+f_1+f_2+...+b=n−1−y(k−1)$. Just apply the formula I just gave and we're done.

Answer (score 0):

The question is equivalent to the following:

> In how many ways may 4 people be seated in a row of 15 chairs given
> that no two people may sit next to one another?

Consider some arrangement of the 4 people as specified, then take one chair out from between each pair of people. What you’re left with is a unique arrangement of $4$ people in 12 chairs without restrictions. Similarly, starting with an unrestricted arrangement of 4 people in 12 chairs, adding a chair between each pair of people gives a unique arrangement of 4 non-adjacent people in 15 chairs. (Convince yourself of these two assertions.) Thus there is a one to one correspondence between the restricted 15-chair arrangements of the problem and unrestricted 12-chair arrangements. The number of unrestricted 12-chair arrangements is the number of ways to choose 4 chairs out of 12
$$\binom{12}{4}$$

Comment: I don't really follow...

Comment: How can you have 12 chairs left when you only take two chair out because in 4 people you have 2 chairs between each pair.

Comment: @NegativeCreep Say the four chairs are $A,B,C,D$ in that order. There's a chair between $A,B$, and $B,C$ and $C,D$. There are $3$.

Comment: Why does it sound like there are invisible chairs that I don't see? Between A and B can't  be other chairs but between A and D we have 2 chairs, between A and C we have two chairs. How can we ever have 3 chairs when the maximum from the first to the final chair is 2? ( from A to D)

Comment: @NegativeCreep Did I misunderstood the problem? Do you agree that the original question is equivalent to the new question I wrote there? If yes, then say the four numbers are $(1,3,5,7)$. There is a number between $1$ and $3$ which is $2$. There's also at least one (in this case it's exactly one) number between $3,5$ and $5,7$. There are $3$ in total.

Comment: 2 Downvotes? What's wrong?

Comment: and with 3 numbers you are referring to 2, 4 and 6 ?

Comment: And yes I understand the problem and agree that it's equivalent to your question.

Comment: I just don't understand the arraignments in your problem. Do you mean that at first all 4 people sit next to each other and then you take out a chair between them because that's impossible. Or do you mean that they sit randomly at 4 places and then you start to take out the chairs between each pair but again you are not making sure that no one is sitting so that you can have a chair in between. Sorry I'm just trying to understand this problem better.

Comment: @NegativeCreep Yes I am referring to $2,4,6$. There must be at least one chair between $A$ and $B$ because they are not adjacent. *Remember that we don't randomly select* $A,B,C,D$. We select them such that no two of $A,B,C,D$ are adjacent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118279/discussion-between-negative-creep-and-adola).

Answer (score 0):

Take out $4$ balls from a line of $15$ balls, so $11$ remain, then  insert the $4$ balls taken out in $\binom{12}4$ ways at the uparrows so no two can be adjacent

$\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow{}$

Now number the balls $1\, thru\, 15$

The ones you inserted back represent the chosen numbers

Comment: It's the same :|

Comment: @Adola: Only, a picture has its own worth.

Comment: so in your picture you have already taken out 4 balls? why do you have 12 choose 4? Why can't it be 15 choose 4 and the minus all the pairs next to each other?

Comment: The $4$ numbers are not to be next to each other. The up arrows in the picture clearly show the $12$ spots allowable so that they aren't adjacent. If you do $\binom{15}4$, how will you count  (to subtract) all possible selections next to each other ?